# jQuery UI autocomplete drop down not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, spotify

I am trying to use the jQuery UI autocomplete feature to search spotify's music library. While everything passes well, and I do get a successful response:

[image: jQuery Autocomplete Spotify Song Search]

There is no drop down suggestions. For instance I was searching "time" and I wanted to see:

- **Time** by Hans Zimmer         <--(This is what I was searching for)
- Back in **time** by Pitbull
- Elevate by Big **Time** Rush

etc. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script>$(function() {$( "#spotify_song_search" ).autocomplete({source: function(request, response) {
        $.get("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json", { q: request.term },function( data ) { alert(data); response(data);});
    },success: function(data) {
            // pass your data to the response callback 
            alert(data); response(data);
        }});});</script>
```

I must be doing something wrong. I also checked the jQuery docs here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ but it doesn't give any explanation why this would occur. And I added alerts to see if I would at least get a response, which I do, but it just returns `[object Object]`. What do I need to do to display search results?

**Error:** `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` on Line 417:
[image]

Comment: No errors in the Console tab?

Comment: Oh never mind, the status is `OK` on your network tab. I'll look into the code.

Comment: Maybe you can show us a little more of code, mainly your `response()` function you call 3 times, and the markup to be able to reproduce it.

Comment: [Make sure it the code is actually valid first](http://www.jshint.com/reports/566015).

Comment: Yeah, the question is not about the success of the request by the fact that there is no drop down results @Incognito.

Comment: @Incognito I think OP should have that function defined somewhere. I just asked for the rest of the code about an hour ago. Do you have the `response()` function defined in your document, right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the `response()` function there is. This code is a couple of days old, I toke a break for a bit. This is all the autocomplete code. I don't believe I have much other JS pertaining to this. I'll take it out.

Comment: I see. Taking a look at the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp), there's actually a response function in the source.

Comment: You need to format the response data, which I assume is being done in the `response()` method. jQueryUI expects a certain format from the `success()` function and if it doesn't match the results will not display. I suspect the conversion from Spotify format to the expected format is not correct. Take a look at the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), in particular the _Remote Datasource_ and _Remote JSONP datasource_ and look at the Network tab in the Console to see the response data format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The autocomplete widget expects data to be formatted in a very specific way so that it can be parsed. The array you supply or pass to the `response` callback must be:

1. An array with strings, *or*
2. An array with objects that have a **label** property, a **value** property, or both.

*(See autocomplete's documentation under "Overview" / "Expected data format" for more information)*

The typical way to do this when you have a data source that you can't change is use `$.map` to transform the results into a format that autocomplete expects:

```
$("#spotify_song_search").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.get("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json", {
            q: request.term
        }, function(data) {
            response($.map(data.tracks, function (el) {
                return el.name;
            }));
        });
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ANmUs/ (Note: this does not appear to be working in Firefox right now; it may be due to the size of the response. It works fine in Chrome though)

Comment: I'm currently using the stable release of chrome and it still doesn't appear to be working. I also don't see any requests being made. I used the console and it gave an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. I think it has something to do with the `$.map` part of the code.

Comment: @PeteA: What are you searching for? I cannot reproduce.

Comment: Sorry, I meant with my site. I added the picture to my post, it gives me an error even though it works fine in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @PeteA: I can't confirm this, but I am concerned the size of the response could be causing problems.

Comment: There was some strage character that was causing the problem. It was not showing up in notepad++ but it was showing up in the HTML randomly. This was the "illegal" character. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This saved my day! I was returning a List of ints and it was not being displayed. I converted it to List of string and by magic autocomplete started to work.